# Redux: How to handle different queries of same type of data?

Tags: wordpress, redux, react-redux, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm looking for best practices of handling same type of data in a redux store while we can have different queries for it.

Imagine a wordpress website, on different pages we have different queries for `posts`. In homepage, for example we fetch 10 most recent posts and save them to redux store, but for a category page we have to again fetch posts in `posts` store, but now we might have different posts which may/may not include the ones we had before.

And this applies to many different pages, like tag,taxonomy,author,date,etc...

So basically having to create a separate store for each case doesn't seem to be a good solution since it might end up with many duplicate values.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the standard reasons why the Flux concept was invented in the first place.  Per Dan Abramov's article on [The Case for Flux](https://medium.com/swlh/the-case-for-flux-379b7d1982c6), caching queries is an excellent use case for a Flux-type architecture.

Going beyond that, the Redux principle of having a ["single source of truth"](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html) applies here, as does the idea of [normalizing data in the store](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html).

Overall, you'd probably want to store your data in a normalized form, with multiple "tables" in your state.  Add each set of results into the state to cache them, and have different parts of the UI read out the specific posts they're interested in as needed.

See the Redux FAQ entry on [organizing nested or duplicate data](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data) for links to more information.